# Akka: can I avoid serialization for local messages?

Tags: scala, serialization, cluster-computing, akka

I use latest Akka release & Akka-cluster. I would like to avoid local messages serialization to reduce memory footprint. Is it possible?

Comment: Local messages are not being serialized.

Comment: A little correction: Local messages are not being serialized if akka.actor.serialize-messages = off (by default).

Comment: This setting is not intended to be used in production.